# Generating QR code from text file with empty lines

Tags: external-files, qrcode

I'm trying to generate a QR code from a text file using the `qrcode` package.

Using `\qrcode{\input{file.txt}}` fails with this error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\in@ #1#2->\begingroup \def \in@@
##1#1{}\toks@ \expandafter {\in@@ #2{}{}#1...
l.20 \qrcode{\input{file.txt}}
```

Using the `catchfile` package:

```
\CatchFileDef\filecontent{file.txt}{}
\expandafter\qrcode\expandafter{\filecontent}
```

Fails with this error:

`! Paragraph ended before \qrcode@in was complete.`

Is there any way to generate a scalable QR code in LaTeX from a text file input?

Edit: complete example

main.tex

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\begin{document}
\qrcode{\input{file.txt}}
\end{document}
```

file.txt

```
this file has
multiple lines

may even ^ contain an empty line
contains --- hyphens
and ends with a newline
```

Comment: please make a complete example that people can run and debug

Comment: the second error (with `catchfile` package) may be caused by an empty line in `file.txt`. But without knowing the file it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Mike yeah it probably is caused by an empty line. When the file doesn't contain an empty line though, what I get is a QR code with the text without spaces and without linebreaks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot have empty lines in the input file without taking special precautions. The following should work:

```
\CatchFileDef\filecontent{file.txt}{\endlinechar=`\^^J \catcode32=12 }
\expandafter\qrcode\expandafter{\filecontent}
```

provided you have no special characters such as `#` or `&` (some similar trick as above might do also for these).

Here’s what I get (scanned, copied and pasted from my phone)

```
this file has
multiple lines

may even ^ contain an empty line
contains --- hyphens
and ends with a newline
```

Comment: It works, but the resulting QR code contains the contents of `file.txt` without spaces and without linebreaks

Comment: @Sorashi Try the current version